# I run the 'npm start' command, but it takes minutes to start the whole Web Project

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react framework I just use npx create-react-app to create new project. when I run npm start it takes minutes to run the project, and the main issue is that while npm start recompiling it takes too much time to update my changes. this happen when I clean npm cache before it was working fine. and help to fix the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post some screenshots to support your questions and make us understand better so that the community can assist you impeccably! In case you're running the application for the first install and spins the dev server, the time it takes in minutes (initially) is okay.

Comment: there is no code error or anything error to show the screenshot. In my first project I use create-react-app to create a project. then suddenly I forcibly I clear the npm cache. after that create-react-app was not working fine, so I uninstall that using npm. after that I use 'npx create-react-app' to create a project but when I am editing the JS code on recompiling it take even about 10 minutes to show the changes in the browser and also the node program reserve too much space on this recompiling operation. I see this in activity monitor of my mac. What is really the problem I don't know.